# (was + was) vs (was + is)

Tags: word-choice, verbs, tenses

I was wondering what's the difference between these two sentences:

> 1. The person who **was** at the head of the demonstration **is** Ms. Tan.
> 2. The person who **was** at the head of the demonstration **was** Ms. Tan.

Comment: In practice, if you were going to use the second form you'd probably just say *The person at the head of the demonstration was Ms. Tan.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sentence 2 merely reports what has happened, whereas 1 suggests some present relevance. For example, a TV presenter might say ‘The person who was at the head of the demonstration is Ms. Tan and we’re delighted to have her on the show tonight.’

Comment: I think we're saying exactly the same thing in different words, 30 secs apart. I can't upvote my own answer, so I'll upvote yours! :)

Comment: Or, to use a relevant example: "The person who was at the head of the demonstration *was* Ms. Tan but *is* Mrs. Jones."

Comment: I've done it for you, FF!

Answer (score 6):

Interpreting these two statements as possible responses to the question *"Who was at the head of the demonstration?"*, you'd probably say **"...is Ms. Tan"** if Ms. Tan were either physically present at the time of the question, or was "metaphorically" present in some way (for example, the questioner had a short list of possible candidates, and wished to establish which one it was).

If Ms. Tan were not present, and wasn't specifically being thought of by the questioner as a possible/probable answer, you'd more likely say **"...was Ms. Tan"**.